# slick slider is not working in RTL when using magento 2 Pagebuilder

Tags: slider, page-builder, slick, arabic

I have created RTL theme for supporting Arabic language, slick slider is not working in RTL when using magento 2 Pagebuilder. when I click on next or previous slide button at that time it is showing blank spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme directory
app/design/frontend/<you_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/

Create Magento_PageBuilder\web\js\resource\slick directory in your custom RTL theme, copy slick.js from vendor, change the below code to fix the issue temporarily.

***FROM***

```
rtl: false
```

***TO***

```
rtl: true
```

Share your thoughts and opinion if you have any other solution according to Magento2 standards.